# Test whether SOAP is running properly

Tags: php, soap, wso2, wsh

Programatically, I want to test whether SOAP is working fine on my clients machine.
The machine can be windows/linux.
I want to get the SOAP version as well.
I'm using PHP.

Similarly, I want to do it for WS02/WSF.

Thanks.

Comment: Which specific SOAP client are you using?  Can you explain what you mean by "SOAP version"?

Answer (score 0):

Set up a SOAP server and run a test script against it. If the test script works, SOAP on the client works.